# How to add values to array from flutter to firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore, I have a document with a field of type array, I want to add datetime values to it from flutter app. Can anyone suggest a way to do it?

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Storing:

Use `DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch`

This would give you an `int` value in return that you can save in Firestore.

Retrieving:

You can easily get `DateTime` from the saved value using `DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(valueSavedInFirestore)`

Comment: Thanks Rohan but I am looking for a way of putting the value(which could be anything) in an array field type or creating the array as a field in firestore document.